# An error occurred while installing rails (4.1.0)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubygems

I'm running the command:

> bundle install

But, I displayme the error:

> An error occurred while installing rails (4.1.0)

I'm not sure how I can resolve it.
I tried uninstalling with:

```
gem uninstall rails
gem install rails

ERROR:  Could not find a valid gem 'rails' (>= 0), here is why:
          Unable to download data from https://rubygems.org/ - no such name (https://api.rubygems.org/quick/Marshal.4.8/rails-4.1.2.gemspec.rz)
ERROR:  Possible alternatives: rails
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried by giving the version?

```
gem 'rails', '~> 4.1.2'
```

Comment: After execute the command: ' rvm osx-ssl-certs update' works! Thanks!